# How to utilize method with RegEx in order to print into a dynamic table on with PHP

Tags: php, regex, loops, methods

I have a list of courses and the hours they require for students to take them. The courses are as follows:

```
CON8101 Residential Building/Estimating 16 hrs/w 
CON8411 Construction Materials I 4 hrs/w 
CON8430 Computers and You 4 hrs/w 
MAT8050 Geometry and Trigonometry 4 hrs/w
```

I have used this RegEx to extract the name of course and the hours each course takes each week. There are more than 4 courses, the 4 are examples above. There can be as many as 50 courses.

```
$courseHoursRegEx = "/\s[0-9]{1,2}\shrs/w/";
$courseNameRegEx = "/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{0,1}\s?/[a-zA-Z]{3,40}/";
```

And applied the following function (not sure if 100% right) to extract the RegEx'd strings. Using $courseLine is the variable I saved the string of each line from a text document that early I have fopened. It keeps track of the total hours that has been extracted from the string.

**$courses is an array of check boxes that the user enters in the html section**

```
$totalHours += GetCourseHours($courseLine);
function GetCourseHours($couseLine)
    {
        if(!preg_match($courseHoursRegEx, $courseLine))
            {
                return $courseLine;
            }
    }
function GetCourseName($courseLine)
    {
        if(!preg_match($courseNameRegEx, $courseLine))
            {
                return $courseLine;
            }
    }
```

I used a foreach loop to output all the selected courses to be sorted out in a table.

```
foreach($courses as $course)
    {
    $theCourse = GetCourseName($course);
    $theHours = GetCourseHours($course)
    }
```

Edit: output code

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $courses; ++$i)
{
printf("<tr><td>\$%.2f</td><td>\$%.2f</td></tr>", $theCourse, $theHours);

}
```

**I am not sure how to output what I have into a dynamic table organized by the course name, and hours for each course. I cannot get my page to run, I cannot find any syntax errors, I was afraid it was my logic.**

Comment: You've not included your output code, so it's hard to be sure what the issue is; but your sample code is setting `$theCourse` and `$theHours` on each run through, so the only value you'll get at the end of the loop is the final course.

Comment: Alright, there is one mistake right away. You've used `/` as your delimiter AND within your regex. Either escape it within the regex (`\/`) or change the delimiter to something like `~` or `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, (after fixing a few minor things within the regexes) you can do all of that in one `preg_` call. Here is how:

```
preg_match_all("~([a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}[A-Z]{0,1}\s.+)\s(\d{1,2})\shrs/w~", $str, $matches);
```

`$str` can either be a multiline string with all rows at once. Or you can pass in a single line at a time. If you pass in all lines at once, `$matches` will afterward look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CON8101 Residential Building/Estimating 16 hrs/w
            [1] => CON8411 Construction Materials I 4 hrs/w
            [2] => CON8430 Computers and You 4 hrs/w
            [3] => MAT8050 Geometry and Trigonometry 4 hrs/w
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CON8101 Residential Building/Estimating
            [1] => CON8411 Construction Materials I
            [2] => CON8430 Computers and You
            [3] => MAT8050 Geometry and Trigonometry
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

Now you can simply iterate over all names in `$matches[1]` and sum up the hours in `$matches[2]`. Notice that those two inner arrays correspond to what's *inside* of the round brackets I used in the regex. These are so called subpatterns, and they *capture* additional (sub-)matches. Also `$matches[0]` will always contain the full match of the whole pattern, but you don't need that in this case.

Comment: IS this a multi-dimensional array? So if I wanted names of a course i need to call $matches[1][1] for CON8411 Construction Materials I?

Comment: @GivenPie yes it is. `$matches[1]` is itself an array of all course names. `$matches[2]` is itself an array of all hours. So as you say `$matches[1][1]` will give you the first name and `$matches[2][1]` the corresponding hours.

Comment: Does it need a constructor to build up the array? I just left it once I havent been able to var_dump($matches) which equals to nothing in the array, but var_dump($matches[1][1]) comes out null. Can $str be replaced with an $arraySessionVariable?

Comment: My bad I didn't understand how I could integrate this method to my problem, now I'm seeing some light.

Comment: No need for a constructor or anything. Just stuff in `$str` which is a multi-line string of all your courses (of just a single course; in that case you don't even need `preg_match_all` but another loop). You **can** call `$matches = array();` beforehand, but in PHP it isn't strictly necessary. So just call the `preg_match_all` function with your courses-string, as I have given it, and then try `var_dump($matches);` afterward.